# Geometric Brownian motion C++

Tags: c++, call, montecarlo, price, gbm

I am trying to devellop a small option pricer using win32 API.
To do that I use monte carlo simulation to compute the price of a call option but there is a mistake in my simulation and I don't see where.
Someone can tell me why the two prices are different ?

The price for a call with the black and scholes formula is 6.84 but the one given by the monte carlo simulation is 7.54.
(There is no error in the price from the black and scholes formula)

This is the code :

```
std::vector<double> vecteur_pas(double T) {
std::vector<double> pas;
pas.push_back(0);
double x = T / nb_pas;
for (int i = 1; i <= nb_pas; i++) {
    pas.push_back(pas[i-1] + x);
}
return pas;


std::vector <double> NormalRnd() {
std::vector <double> brow;
brow.push_back(0);
double unif_1, unif_2;
for (int i = 0; i < nb_pas; i++) {
    unif_1 = (double(rand() + 0.5)) / (double(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
    unif_2 = (double(rand() + 0.5)) / (double(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
    brow.push_back(sqrt(-2 * log(unif_1)) * cos(2 * M_PI * unif_2));
}
return brow;



std::vector<double> MBG(double S, double mu, double vol, double T) {
std::vector<double> traj;
traj.push_back(S);
std::vector <double> b =NormalRnd();
std::vector<double> pas = vecteur_pas(T);
double drift = 0.0;
double diffusion = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= nb_pas; i++) {
    drift = (mu - 0.5 * pow(vol, 2)) * (pas[i]-pas[i-1]);
    diffusion = vol * b[i] * sqrt(pas[i] - pas[i - 1]);
    traj.push_back(traj[i - 1] * exp(drift + diffusion));
}
return traj;
```

The MBG function is called in a loop after :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 1000) == 0)
            {
                SendDlgItemMessage(Calcul, IDE_PB, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
            }
            vector<double> proc_prix = MBG(actif.S, actif.r, actif.v, actif.T);
            double last_value = proc_prix[proc_prix.size() - 1];
            Prime = Prime + std::max(last_value - actif.K, 0.0);
        }
        Prime = Prime / 100000;
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyw0E.png)

Comment: You might want to read this: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf  I suspect you're running into an accumulation of small floating-point math errors. Also, don't use float/double for money. You might consider using a binary-coded decimal library or something like GMP: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: If you indent your code correctly we might be able to read it

Comment: You also do not have balanced braces in your first three functions, or what I assume are supposed to be functions